# How to find the analytic function $f=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, partial-derivative, indefinite-integrals

How to find $u$ and $v$ such that $f=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic, knowing that $\cfrac{v}{u}=\phi(y)$.

I tried writing $v(x,y)=u(x,y)\phi(y)$ and then calculating the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$:

a) $\cfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}=\cfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\phi(y)$ ;

b) $\cfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}=\cfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\phi(y)+u(x,y)\phi'(y)$

From the first equation, after replacing $\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}$ by $-\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}$ from the Cauchy-Riemann equations, I find that $$u(x,y)=-\int{\phi(y)\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}dy}$$

Now how should I calculate this integral?

Is there another way to find $u$ and $v$?

Comment: You don't calculate that integral. You use *both* equations and the C-R equations to get an expression for $u_x$ that does not involve $v$ or differentiation or integration by $y$. Solve that equation, but recognize that the "constant" is a function of $y$. Solve the equations again to isolate $u_y$, and plug in the expression for $u$ obtained to before to figure out what the "constant" function must be. Once $u$ is found, C-R alone will give you $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking derivative of $$\frac v u =\phi(y)$$ with respect to $x$, one gets $$\Rightarrow \frac{v_xu-vu_x}{u^2}=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{v_x}{u_x}=\frac v u,$$ which by C-R implies $$\frac{-u_y}{v_y}=\frac v u,$$ or $$uu_y+vv_y=0,$$ namely $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(u^2+v^2)=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\log(u^2+v^2)=0.$$Now $\log(u^2+v^2)$ being harmonic, this shows that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(\log(u^2+v^2))=0$$ $$\Rightarrow \log(u^2+v^2)=a_1x+b_1,$$ or $$u^2+v^2=e^{a_1x+b_1},$$ where $a_1,b_1$ are constant. Applying the relation $v=\phi u$, one now has $$(1+\phi^2)u^2=e^{a_1x+b_1},$$ which shows that up to sign $$u=\frac {e^{ax+b}}{\sqrt{1+\phi^2}},$$ $$v=\frac {\phi e^{ax+b}}{\sqrt{1+\phi^2}},$$ where $a=\frac 12a_1,b=\frac 12b_1$. Applying C-R, i.e. $u_y=-v_x$, one gets after canceling factors that $\phi'=a(1+\phi^2)$. This is a separable equation, so after integration one has $$\tan^{-1}\phi=ay+C,$$ or $$\phi=\tan(ay +C),$$ where $C$ is a constant. Now by simple trig identities, one can express $u,v$ as $$u=\pm e^{ax+b}\cos(ay +C),$$ $$v=\pm e^{ax+b}\sin(ay +C),$$ which represent the general solutions and are easily checked to satisfy the C-R equations.

**Example**: $f(z)=e^z=e^x\cos(y)+i e^x\sin(y)$ with $\phi(y)=\tan(y).$

Comment: How did you get from $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(u^2+v^2)=0$ to $\Rightarrow \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\log(u^2+v^2)=0$ ?

Comment: By Chain Rule, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\log U=\frac 1U\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and your hints. There's still one thing that I can't figure out. Why do we use the second order derivative of the logarithm to derive $a_1x+b_1$ and not just $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(u^2+v^2)=0$ ?

Comment: The difference is that $\log(u^2+v^2)$ is harmonic but $u^2+v^2$ is not. Using only $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u^2+v^2)=0$ would show that $u^2+v^2$ is a function of $x$, which is a less precise result.